# How can I achieve "live" static client-side resources (to prevent restarting the project server between CSS & JS changes during development)?

Tags: vert.x

Currently my Vert.x project 'wraps' everything (including static, client-side files) in a jar when I run it on my development machine. This will be fine for Production, but during development I have to restart/rerun the server every time I make a change in a CSS or JS file. Very time-consuming.

If I'm using the correct terminology here, **how do I get my StaticHandler to serve static resources from the file system rather than from the classpath**.  (Honestly I have searched and searched and can't figure out a solution based on what I've read.)

Thank you!

*Vert.x 3.9.1

IntelliJ IDEA 2020*

Answer (score 0):

I found my error after someone else's code example clued me in.

```
StaticHandler staticHandler = StaticHandler.create()  
    .setAllowRootFileSystemAccess(true)  
    .setCachingEnabled(false)  
    .setWebRoot("/home/  ...  /static")  
    ;
```

The above code sample does work.  When setting the web root path, I had not been starting the path with a "/".  Doing this resolved the issue.